# pasar un valor de id por una URL de un button

Tags: php, html

Hola quisiera saber como pasar el valor del id= informacion por la URL del input type="submit"

el codigo es el siguiente:

```html
 <div id="informacion">0</div>  

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index3.php?var= <?php echo $id['informacion'];?>">
  <label>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Quisiera recibir en la pagina index3.php  el valor del id=informacion que en este caso es "0"

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, necesitas pasar el valor que tienes en el div con id="informacion" a tu archivo index3.php??

Comment: si asi es......

Answer (score 1):

Hola para solucionar este problema debes utilizar DOM.
Supongamos que la página donde esta el formulario se llama "login.php".

Primero el action del formulario debe indicar la página donde se enviará, que creo es index3.php, luego en esta página debe ir el siguiente código dentro de las etiquetas php correspondientes:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://localhost/php/login.php'; //Url de donde esta el formulario

    //Se obtiene el contenido de la página del formulario  
        $html = file_get_contents($url);
    //Se genera el DOM  
        $doc = new DOMDocument;  
        $doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET);  

    //Se obtiene el elemento mediante su id (div)  
        $texto = $doc->getElementById('informacion');  

    //Obtener el texto del elemento  
        $textoDiv = $texto->textContent;  

    //Imprimir el resultado en el archivo index3.php  
        echo "Texto: " . $textoDiv;  
?>
```

Con esto veras el contenido del div en la página index3.php

Espero te ayude saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero el problema es que ese div id =informacion  que en este caso tu supusiste que estaba en login.php, es modificado en esa pagina antes de redirigirme a index3.php  por lo que necesito que se mande luego de esa modificacion, ya que si lo hago como tu lo hiciste recien obtengo el valor predeterminado del div id= informacion.

Disculpa si es un poco complicado, pero lo que me serviria para solucionar mi problema seria por ejemplo que me dijeras como pasar el contenido de un div a variable php en la misma pagina para despues pasar esa esa variable php por url

Answer (score 0):

Un poco más sencillo, en jQuery y AJAX:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var informacion = $("#informacion").html();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "index3.php",
        data: {
            informacion: informacion
        }
    }).done(function(r) {
        alert("Hecho!");
    });
});
```

O más sencillo aún, en el form, añade el campo informacion como input, si quieres que el div siga ahí, lo puedes añadir con el type hidden:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index3.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="informacion" value="<?php echo $id['informacion'];?>">
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" />
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, y en la pagina index3.php como obtengo el valor de $id['informacion'] ??

Comment: Como el form es method="post" con $valor = $_POST["informacion"];